# Grunt - pkg is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

**Executing the command:**
Default task is concat.

```
grunt -v
```

**I get the following Error message:**

> Verifying property concat.dist exists in config...Warning: An error
>   occurred while processing a template (pkg is not defined). Use --force
>   to continue.

I guess, pkg is the package.json.
I use the placeholder

> pkg.name
>    in the Gruntfile.js.

What is the problem here?

**Gruntfile.js** excerpt:

```
 concat: {
            options: {
                // define a string to put between each file in the concatenated output
                separator: ';'
            },
            dist: {
                // the files to concatenate
                src: ['www/**/*.js'],
                // the location of the resulting JS file
                dest: 'www-built/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
            }
        }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myprodpackage",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "description": "test package",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bloodhound": "^1.0.0",
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.13",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "gulp-minify": "^0.0.14",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2",
    "respond.js": "^1.4.2",
    "text": "^2.0.15",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "legends",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your Gruntfile is lacking a section that sets a `pkg` property in your config. Something like this is commonly found in most Gruntfile's.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
});
```

Adding that property should make `pkg.name` the same as what is in your `package.json`.